# Unable to refer JSF managed bean from external jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using Primefaces (JSF implementation) for creating my web application. I have kept Controllers (JSF beans) + Services in one application and Contracts (Spring JDBC) in another application. I have generated jars manually and I have kept Contracts-jar and Controller + Services-jar in lib folder of web appllication. In faces-config i have written.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config 
          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.0">




<!-- JSF and Spring are integrated -->
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>


</faces-config>
```

During startup, application is unable to find the controllers (JSF managed beans) from external jar. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "... unable to find ...". ClassNotFoundException? Use `jar tf external.jar` to inspect the contents of `external.jar`. Does it contain the unlocated controller classes?

Comment: Where is `faces-config` located?

Comment: Right. I got ClassNotFoundException. @ChristophS

Comment: It was under WebContent->WEB-INF @XtremeBiker